# Bootstrap 4 vertical alignment of progress bar

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'd like to vertically center bootstrap 4's progress bar in a column. This seems like it should be simpler than I'm experiencing. I've tried align-content-center, align-items-center, and my-auto, various containing boxes with various combinations of alignment classes. I obviously don't have a real command of vertical alignment. What's preventing it from moving?

```css
.progress-bar {
  width: 65%;
  background-color: ;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-3 p-3 bg-warning">The box to the right shows a progress bar that should be vertically aligned</div>
    <div class="col-6 bg-dark">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar bg-info"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 bg-warning"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codpen link](https://codepen.io/cmulatz/pen/RwPVogy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertical alignment is often a bit harder than simply using `vertical-align: middle`. In your particular case, you can position your progress bar by using `position: absolute`. You set it to 50% from top and 0 from left, and use `transform` to offset it by its own height. In this case the element will also need to set the elements width.

```
.progress{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(0%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping bootstrap 5 or flexbox would have better vertical alignment options, but for now this does what I need.